# Setup CPE as access point for Wifi Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

I have a Telenet systems" Model: "TWI 1040 - PE" CPE.

I want to use this CPE as a Access Point connected to PC via Ethernet port to access my Wifi connection

SSID of Wifi Connection - Linkstar ; Mac ID - **:**:**:**:**:** ; Password - *****
I can telnet into the device. Have User / Pass
I can access the web config. Have User / Pass

I donot know anything about telnet/unix/linux. It tells me it is running BusyBox v1.01

Has the following directories in root
bin, dev, etc, lib, lost+found, proc, root, sbin, sys, tmp, usr, var

through the web config for AP Scan. It asks for SSID and displays MAC address of the Linkstar device along with frequency channel 1.

have two tabs 'network' and 'Wlan config' but dont think much can be configured from here. will have to make changes through telnet only.

the Linkstar device IP address 192.168.1.1,
the Telenet device IP address is  192.168.0.254

please help